# Extract Response from query string in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Column Name : a1

value : pkid=11&ordernumber=TOD100712285&ordervalue=252&response=NA&scheduleId=32

Need to get value of `response` that is `NA`.

Is it possible in mysql.

Comment: Answer is : **SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a1, '&', 4), '&', -1)**

Comment: you should add this as an update to your question or better yet post your own answer and close it..